# Felt pad for shower install?

Tags: shower

So I am putting in a basic 60x30 shower base in my basement.  Shower sits on my basement slab, connects to the drain.  All square and level.  The instructions say I can put a felt pad down instead of mortar.  Is this just a 60x30 pad that I would get in the flooring section of a store just so the base isn't sitting on the hard floor?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oHIZ.jpg)

[image]

Comment: do you have pictures of the base, an underneath picture would be great?

Comment: Picture has been added

Comment: Where is that thing draining too?   I don't see pipes in that hole.

Comment: That is a 4 inch pipe that goes to the main line.  What you can't see down there is it is actually a P trap under the slab      When the house was build back in 1950, the owner wanted a basement bathroom.   Just never got to doing it

Comment: You can also use roofing tar paper.

Comment: I have a cement tile floor in my bathroom.I just had a contractor put in a new shower .he used the felt pad under the pan and it is rock solid.this contractor has been in business for almost 20 years.he said he has used mortar on some pans and the felt pad on others.it is just according to the flooring.so far i love my new shower.

Answer (score 1):

A 60x30 shower is a pretty decent sized shower.  Most shower pans have the "floor" layer that recedes to the drain and the slope leaves a vacant/hollow layer underneath the pan.

I have only seen a handful of pans in my life that actually sit completely flat on a floor - it is usually just the drain part and the outside.

Felt is used when a pan does sit flat or if there is a bed that the pan sits on that is already "curved" for the pan.   Simply for a basement floor I would never put a felt pad down.

There is a good chance if you did just put a pad down then the pan would feel hollow standing on it.   And the other issue is that depending on how the pan is made it could "flatten" (yours would not flatten but the mortar would allow you to correct the drain height) and not drain right.   Not a huge issue if the pan top is plastic but if it contains cut granite/tile/whatever it may not dry out properly.

My advice would be to pack in the pan to achieve a proper drain slope.   The mortar should  be solid to pan and I would estimate fill 90% of the hollow area - you don't want it just spilling out.   Doing this right can make a cheap shower pan seem expensive and solid and its just the right way.

On a side note the mortar and bucket is probably cheaper than a felt pad.   You want to put the mortar in right when you are hooking up your drain.

Comment: After seeing a picture - that is a good pan.  I like the design.  I could actually see that pan working with felt on plywood which I normally don't do.   I don't see what is keeping the pan from wiggling on something as hard as concrete - so def suggesting mortar.   And I swear the mortar will be quicker than the felt - you have to shop around for a felt pad to fit the mortar is at any big box.